# A basic question on layers, sublayers, and cartodb.js

Tags: carto, carto-js, infowindow

I am really new to cartodb and have spent a number of hours trying to figure out the distinction between layers and sublayers.  Specifically within cartodb.js.   For example, I have a map with two layers that I created using cartodb.  I then use cartodb.createVis to get at it from javascript.   Most things work, but to set an infowindow on a sublayer, I seem to have to do:

```
layers[1].layers[1].sub.infowindow.set(stuff)
```

but, when I define the infowindow's template, only some of the template tags seem to be populated.  Any ideas?  In particular:

1)  Is there clear documentation somewhere on layers, sublayers, events, and infowindows somewhere?

2)  Is there any way within an infowindow to inspect {{content.data}} to find out what fields it actually has?

Comment: That is really two questions, which is generally discouraged.